# Python script not working beyond a certain line in the code

Tags: python

I am pretty new to coding in blender, just two days since I started.

I am trying to create a code that will align the local axis of an object to the local axis of another without changing its mesh alignment. So to do this I align the object in Object Mode and then go to edit mode to invert the changes.

I created a basic code but it seems to not work after a certain line.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix
from math import pi


class OrientLocalAxis(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Orients Local Axis to another Object without changing current 
Structual view"""
    bl_label = "Orient Local Axis to object"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_OLAxis"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene 
        obj = context.object 

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Active object is: " + obj.name)             
        layout.prop_search(scene, "Epty", scene, "objects")

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("object.align_local_axis")


def main(context):

    #-------------Obj = Object we want to change----------------------------
    #------------TObj = Target Object we want to Align to-------------------

    scene = bpy.context.scene
    TObj = scene.objects[scene.Epty]

    TObjIRE = TObj.rotation_euler
    TObjIRM = TObjIRE.to_matrix() 

    ObjIRE = bpy.context.active_object.rotation_euler
    ObjPos = bpy.context.active_object.location    
    # We will need this later for rotating the mesh
    ObjIRM = ObjIRE.to_matrix()

    #We Find out the Rotation Matrix to transform TObj to Obj---------------
    # We will use this transform the mesh back to its original orientation--

    ITM = ObjIRM  #ITM is for Inverse Transformation Matrix


    # We set the orientation of the Object to the target

    bpy.context.active_object.rotation_euler = TObjIRE

    #Now we go to Edit Mode and select all Vertices

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
```

Doesn't seem to do anything after this point

```
    mesh = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(bpy.context.active_object.data)

    for v in mesh.verts: # Not sure if selection is needed Check Later
        v.select = True

    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.context.scene.objects.active

    bmesh.ops.rotate(mesh, cent=(0,1,0), matrix=TOBjIRM, verts=mesh.verts)

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')


# Operator Definition

class AlignLocalAxis(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.align_local_axis"
    bl_label = "Align Local Axis"



def execute(self, context):
    main(context)
    return {'FINISHED'}







 #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(AlignLocalAxis)
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.Scene.Epty = bpy.props.StringProperty()


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(AlignLocalAxis)
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    del bpy.types.Object.Epty


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

So the code doesn't run after it goes to edit mode, essentially from the for loop on wards. It doesn't select all the vertices or rotate them.
I copied the code from the 'for loop' on wards till  'Object mode' and ran it as a separate code and it works just fine.

ps: I am not concerned about whether the code will serve my purpose or not, I would prefer fixing it myself. Thank you.

Comment: You may want to run blender from console in order to get the stack trace in case of errors.

Comment: I think the problem was actually me missing to add bmesh, Its weired because it did not show any errors. Even now when I remove bmesh it shows no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have copy-pasted the code in blender and with few changes, same variable wrong names like TObjIRM and TOBjIRM for the same var, include import bmesh at beginning,... the code works now without errors.
This is what you want? ;)

```
import bpy, bmesh
from mathutils import Matrix
from math import pi

class OrientLocalAxis(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Orients Local Axis to another Object without changing current 
Structual view"""
    bl_label = "Orient Local Axis to object"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_OLAxis"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene 
        obj = context.object 

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Active object is: " + obj.name)             
        layout.prop_search(scene, "Epty", scene, "objects")

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("object.align_local_axis")


def main(context):

    #-------------Obj = Object we want to change----------------------------
    #------------TObj = Target Object we want to Align to-------------------

    scene = bpy.context.scene
    TObj = scene.objects[scene.Epty]

    TObjIRE = TObj.rotation_euler
    TObjIRM = TObjIRE.to_matrix() 

    ObjIRE = bpy.context.active_object.rotation_euler
    ObjPos = bpy.context.active_object.location    
    # We will need this later for rotating the mesh
    ObjIRM = ObjIRE.to_matrix()

    #We Find out the Rotation Matrix to transform TObj to Obj---------------
    # We will use this transform the mesh back to its original orientation--

    ITM = ObjIRM  #ITM is for Inverse Transformation Matrix


    # We set the orientation of the Object to the target

    bpy.context.active_object.rotation_euler = TObjIRE

    #Now we go to Edit Mode and select all Vertices

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')

    mesh = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(bpy.context.active_object.data)

    for v in mesh.verts: # Not sure if selection is needed Check Later
        v.select = True

    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.context.scene.objects.active

    bmesh.ops.rotate(mesh, cent=(0,1,0), matrix=TObjIRM, verts=mesh.verts)

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')


# Operator Definition

class AlignLocalAxis(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.align_local_axis"
    bl_label = "Align Local Axis"

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}

 #--------------------------------------------------------------------------         
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(AlignLocalAxis)
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.Scene.Epty = bpy.props.StringProperty()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Actually It was the bmesh, the variable mistake was added when I tried to debug.